# Changing the order in a list by comparing it to another list

Tags: python, list

I am having trouble manipulating the element's place in my list. I have the following code:

```
name= ['a', 'b', 'c','d','e']
year= [10,20,30,40,50]
ID= ['a', 'c', 'd']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name' : name, 'age' : year})
x= list(set(name).intersection(ID))
print (x)
y=df[df['Name'].isin(x)]['age']
print(y)
```

The output I get is:

```
['c', 'a', 'd']
0    10
2    30
3    40
```

This is where I am confused. List `name` and `year` are supposed to be related, so `a and 10, b and 20....` But when I print `x` and `y`, I get `c and 10, a and 30, b and 40`. I think python automatically sorts `y` from ascending to descending. How do I fix `y` to get `30, 10, 40` instead of `10, 30, 40`.

Comment: It doesn't sort by descending. It is just that set isn't for storing elements in order and the order gets jumbled up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You confused because after convert `list` to `set` you break the order of the original list, so to fix it:

instead

```
x= list(set(name).intersection(ID))
```

you should filter your original list, for example by list comprehension:

```
x= [i for i in name if i in ID]
```

Answer (score 1):

To get what you are looking for you can just use the same subset from the df, like this

```
name= ['a', 'b', 'c','d','e']
year= [10,20,30,40,50]
ID= ['a', 'c', 'd']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name' : name, 'age' : year})
x= list(set(name).intersection(set(ID)))
print (x)
y=df[df['Name'].isin(x)].age.to_list()
y1= df[df['Name'].isin(x)].Name.to_list()
print(y)
print(y1)
```

result

```
[10, 30, 40]
['a', 'c', 'd']
```

`y` and `y1` will print out how you are expecting, where they are matched

Comment: You should make a set out of ID

Comment: That helped. Thank you